# How can I address a div from another div (the div doing the addressing is target for content pages)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day everyone. After 4 days of googling I have come to ask you here. I am trying to address a div with CSS from another div that is the target for all content pages. CSS works fine in the div calling it but in the other div it only returns an empty result (HMTL collection with length 0). Have I done something wrong in the selector? The page that is to be loaded into the target div exists, of course. Code follows...

```js
function small() {
   window.fs = 1;
   console.log("fs: ", window.fs);
   console.log("small rennt");
   var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "1rem";
   }
   var elms = window.document.getElementsByClassName('item');
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "1rem";
   }
}


function normal() {
   window.fs = 2;
   console.log("fs: ", window.fs);
   var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
   console.log("normal rennt");
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
   }
   var elms = window.document.getElementsByClassName('item');
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
   }
}


function big() {
   window.fs = 3;
   console.log("fs: ", window.fs);
   var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
   console.log("big rennt");
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "2rem";
   }
   var elms = window.document.anchors;
   console.log("elms: ", elms);
   for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   elms[i].style.fontSize = "2rem";
   }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

#hirsch {
  width: 110%;

  height: 100%;

    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000a0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-image: url(thyralogo.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

}


#logo > #hirsch {
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  vertical-align: bottom;

}

h4 {
font-size: large; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; background-color: cyan;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  <!-- width: 20%;    -->
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

 /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

.menu {
background-color: #a0a0a0; width: 20%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden;
}

#main {
background-color: #00a000; width: 80%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden; border: none;
}


#elf {

background-color: #0000c0;
color: #a0a0a0;
font-weight: bold;
}

#elf:hover {

background-color: #0000e0;
color: #e0e0e0;
font-weight: bold;

}

#divine {

background-color: #a000a0;
color: #c0c000;
font-weight: bold;

}


#divine:hover {

background-color: #c000c0;
color: #f0f000;
font-weight: bold;

}





/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.divine-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.divine:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



.divine-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}


.divine-content + a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.size {
   display: inline;
   color: black;
   background-color: red;
   text-align: center;



}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
#divine-content + a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
#divine:hover + .divine-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
#divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}


.sizlinks {
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   color: black;
   background-color: red;
   border: none;
}

.sz1 {
   font-size: 100%;
}


.sz2 {
   font-size: 120%;
}


.sz3 {
   font-size: 140%;
}


.sz4 {
   font-size: 160%;
}


.hsz1 {
   font-size: 140%;
}


.hsz2 {
   font-size: 160%;
}


.hsz3 {
   font-size: 180%;
}


.hsz4 {
   font-size: 200%;
}


#b1 {
   font-size: 1rem;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #a0a0a0;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
}


#b1:hover {
   font-size: 1rem;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   cursor: grab;
   background-color: #c0c0c0;
}


#b2 {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #a0a0a0;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
}


#b2:hover {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   cursor: grab;
   background-color: #c0c0c0;
}


#b3 {
   font-size: 2rem;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #a0a0a0;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
}



#b3:hover {
   font-size: 2rem;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   cursor: grab;
   background-color: #c0c0c0;
}


.item {
   font-size: normal;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Thyra Kristin Lang</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="menu" background-color="005000">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

     <h4>Hauptmenü</h4>
     <div class="item"><a href="willkommen.html" target="main">Willkommens-Seite</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="divine1.html" target="main" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="elf1.html" target="main" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="poetry.html" target="main" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="size.html" target="main">Barrierefreiheit</a></div>
     <br>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="logo"></div>

<div id="main" name="main" src="size.html" background-color="005000">blub</div>



</div>

</body>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="Freya Bremer">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>


</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
<p class="content">Hier kann man die Schriftgröße einstellen...<br></p>
<span><button id="b1" onclick="small()">Normale Schrift</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="normal()">Große Schrift</button>
<button id="b3" onclick="big()">Sehr große Schrift</button></span>
</body>
</html>
```

TIA for your answers.

Comment: Could you describe why you have two documents, with the buttons to change the font size being in a different document from the one that holds the relevant elements? I don't understand what is happening

Comment: Gladly. The whole site has much more content (12 pages ATM) and the one with the size-changing should change the font-size for the whole site and all pages that will be called afterwards. It is just one of the pages.

Comment: It might be worth putting your file through a validator.

Comment: What is that (a validator) and what would that do?

Comment: It will tell you whether you have legal HTML and CSS. I tried the W3c validator and it told me it was ignoring the second doctype. I am confused because I've not seen one document try to access another before in the way your code does. Hopefully someone who understands will see this and find a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time.